# Highlighting tab view pager android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

Hi i am using tab layout with view pager and in FragmentPagerAdapter i am using custom layout to define each view according to position.Now i want to achieve this thing as seen in this image(the one selected is more white than others). How to highlight custom view with different shading as in this image. My all tabs are same wheather are selected or unselected.
Earlier i used default text and it was working but now i am using custom view with image and text and i don't know how to apply it to custom view.
[image]

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: In this article this problem is also not solved for custom view

Comment: I think Indicator color will change color of that yellow line not add opacity to custom layout

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
...onCreate(){ 
...    
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new    OnTabChangeListener() { 
@Override public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {    

setTabColor(tabHost);
   } 
});    
setTabColor(tabHost);
... 
} //Change The Backgournd Color of Tabs   

public void 
setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) { 
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)     
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_CYAN); //unselected   
if(tabhost.getCurrentTab()==0) {
tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab())
.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_RED); //1st tab selected
 }else{ tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BLUE); //2nd tab selected 
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is snippet code to override text style and selected text color

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout"> 
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item> 
<item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tab_text_act</item> 
</style> 
<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item> 
<item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item> 
</style>
```

And here is snippet code for layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
```

Comment: I am using tab layout and not using TabHost can it be solved without TabHost?

Comment: Will it work for both icon and text as i want to add opacity 50% to tabs that are not selected, i want to know how apply opacity to custom layout according to tabs selection?

Answer (score 1):

Specify tabIndicatorColor="#00000000" like below :-

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#00000000"
                    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For Opacity and other stuffs refer the below link :-

[TabLayout](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: I wanted to add opacity.